# React Native - Call method from a function passed as prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working with a library called [react-native-linkedin](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-linkedin), this library gives an option to override a method called renderButton(), to create the button which triggers login process.

Now I need to call a method open inside class LinkedInModal, this class is the same that receives renderButton as prop.

How can I call this "open" method from my renderButton method?, I have tried:

```
LinkedInModal.open()
```

Method looks like:

```
renderButton = () => {
        return (React.createElement(TouchableOpacity, 
                  { accessibilityComponentType: 'button', accessibilityTraits: ['button'], 
                    onPress: LinkedInModal.open() 
                  },
                React.createElement(Text, {style: {color: "#FFF"}}, "Continue with Linkedin")));
    }
```

And it is passed to the component as:

```
<LinkedInModal
                        clientID="..."
                        clientSecret="..."
                        redirectUri="https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps"
                        onSuccess={token => this.linkedinLogin(token.access_token)}
                        linkText="Continue with Linkedin"
                        renderButton={this.renderButton}
                    />
```

But it does not work.

Error I get is:

```
    TypeError: _reactNativeLinkedin.default.open is not a function. 
(In '_reactNativeLinkedin.default.open()', '_reactNativeLinkedin.default.open' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to create a reference:

```
linkedRef = React.createRef();
```

then when calling the component, pass it as prop:

```
            <LinkedInModal
                ref={this.linkedRef}
                clientID="..."
                clientSecret="..."
                redirectUri="https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps"
                onSuccess={token => this.linkedinLogin(token.access_token)}
                linkText="Continue with Linkedin"
                renderButton={this.renderButton}
            />
```

And in my custom method use it:

```
onPress={() => this.linkedRef.current.open()}>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not wrapping the `Text` correctly.
Can you try:

```
renderButton = () => (
  <TouchableOpacity 
      accessibilityComponentType="button" 
      accessibilityTraits={['button']}
      onPress={() => LinkedInModal.open()}>
    <Text style={{color: "#FFF"}}> Continue with Linkedin </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I get same error, that the function is not defined, I think is missing something when calling the method from LinkedinModal. I have added the error I get to the question.